# Shift/Reduce conflict found in state in Java Cup

Tags: java, parsing, grammar, cup

I am trying to write parsing in java cup but I get conflict

```
start with prog;

prog ::= header;
header ::= t1 t3 t2 | t3 t1 t2 | t2 t3 t1 | t1 t2 t3 | t2 t1 t3 | t3 t2 t1;

t1 ::= TOK1;
t2 ::= TOK2 | TOK2 TOK2 ;
t3 ::= | t3 TOK3;
```

I got this error;

```
Warning : *** Shift/Reduce conflict found in state #3
  between t3 ::= (*) 
  and     t1 ::= (*) TOK1 
  under symbol TOK1
  Resolved in favor of shifting.
```

Can someone explain where I did mistake?

Comment: I can't see how this questions relates to Java, and it sounds like a homework or a quiz or something, then you should consider reading and practicing more. Google what is shift/reduce and I'm sure It will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t3` can be empty (it matches a sequence of zero or more `TOK3` tokens). That creates an ambiguity, because an input with no `TOK3`s can match more than one of the alternatives for `header`.

This is ambiguous despite the fact that all the possibilities reduce to the same non-terminal, because each production has a different reduction action, and the grammar has no way to know which action to perform. As noted in the conflict report, the parser will shift rather than reduce. For example,  if the first input is `TOK1`, the parser could assume the input will match `t1 t2 t3` or `t1 t3 t2`, in which case the sequence of `TOK3`s will come later, or it could assume the input is `t3 t1 t2` with an empty `t3`, in which it must do the action for an empty `t3` before proceeding with the parse. Choosing to shift means rejecting the possibility of an empty `t3` at the beginning of the input.

In this particular case, the default shift is probably not going to cause problems. It means that an input consisting only of `TOK1` and `TOK2` will always be parsed with an empty `t3` at the end, but if that's OK, then you can feel free to ignore the warning.

So-called "nullable non-terminals" are often the cause of shift-reduce conflicts precisely of this form. It's often useful to avoid them; instead of making possibly empty lists, a better solution is often to make the list non-terminal match one or more elements, and then make it optional by adding productions in which the list is absent. In other words, instead of

```
header: t3 t1 t2
t3    :  
      | t3 TOK3
```

use

```
header: t3 t1 t2
      |    t1 t2
t3    : TOK3
      | t3 TOK3
```

That solution can lead to undesirable code duplication, but it's an easy way to solve shift-reduce conflicts due to nullable non-terminals.